# Where is the session timeout defined?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2005

I am using VS2005 C# ASP.NET 2.0.

I want to know where can I configure my session timeout in my web.config.

The default timeout value is shorter then the value of the timeout script I ran on each webpage, resulting in the webpage being brought to the login page with URL like

`http://<IP>/App/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fSoD%2fCommon%2fIUVViewUser.aspx`

May I know where is the value set or what is the default timeout value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is 20 minutes you override it here:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="30" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: I have tried to set it to 1min, but it doesn't seem to timeout

Comment: Are you using the built-in .NET forms authentication?

Comment: Yes, here is the code `forms` tag in my *web.config*:`<forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/dataRefresh.aspx" timeout="10" />`

Comment: The timeout on the auth cookie is set to 10 minutes.  It is possible that the session is automatically re-initialized when visiting the page again. Try setting it to 1 minute as well and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Use timeout in web.config, can also use timespan--20 minutes is default, also The timeout attribute cannot be set to a value that is greater than 525,601 minutes (1 year) for the in-process and state-server modes.

> ```
>  sessionState 
> mode="[Off|InProc|StateServer|SQLServer|Custom]"
> timeout="number of minutes"
> ```

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET 2.0, use have to check in the IIS.

Open the IIS, click on the Application Pools, Select the Application pool for your application.

Right Click on that, Select Properties.

In the Performance tab, Set the idle timeout as your desired minutes for "shutdown worker processes after being idle for ..... minutes".

Apart from this you have to set the timeout in web.config as said by the other friends.

Hope this works.

Comment: timeout="521101" worked on my MVC 4.7 project

Answer (score 0):

You can set it through IIS admin on your server, or if you want to make sure it's correct even in development you should be able to set it through your web.config. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx) is a link to the element information for .net 4.0, I assume it is at least similar in 2.0.